# Div and CSS based solution for container with fixed/not fixed height

Tags: html, css, layout

I have situation like in following example (see in chrome):
http://jsfiddle.net/3fLP6/49/

There are div rows with some content and one div with variable content which should fill rest of available height. Everything works fine in Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Android/iOS but I cannot find solution for IE (I need solution for IE7+) is there any other way to acomplish this in IE?

Comment: not possible through CSS only

Comment: hmm, it is possible in Chrome and other modern browsers, that is why I thought it should be some kind of solution for IE

Comment: @Irek And what previous experience would lead you to that silly idea? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you want a header that always sits on the top, a footer that always sits on the bottom, and one div that fills the rest of the available space; no matter how small or large its contents are. I use these terms in the rest of my answer.

Well, there are to my knowledge three methods to do this in IE7+:

1. Use the `position: fixed` CSS property to position the header, footer and the body. This means you have to set the header to a top position of 0 pixels and the footer to a bottom position of 0 pixels. Furthermore, you have to set the top and bottom property of the body `div` to the height of the header and footer respectively. Consequently, this method requires you to know the exact height of both the header and the footer. Unfortunately, some older browsers (e.g. IE6) don't support `position: fixed`, so if support for those browser is important, you should go with one of the other options;
2. Use percentages to specify the height's of all the `div`'s. Clearly, this is quite easy. However, if you want to set a specific height for the header and footer, that isn't possible;
3. You can also create a `div` width a height of 100% which will act as the body `div`. On top of that you position the header and footer `div`'s using `position: absolute` (because of that, this will also work in older browsers). Then, you add to the body element two other elements: one `div` at the top and one `div` at the bottom. These `div`'s have to be the same height as the header and footer respectively, because these two elements will make sure that the scrollbar is showed when necessary. Of course, you'll need to set `overflow: auto` on the body `div`;
4. Finally, you can also change the height of the body `div` using JavaScript when the window is resized. A big disadvantage of this method is that JavaScript is required, and therefore this wouldn't be my choice.

I hope I helped. Please ask any question if I wasn't clear (enough).